# Сервер IIS возвращает в качестве ответа на запросы по SOAP ошибку 500

Tags: php, sql-server, iis

При помощи  SoapClient пытаюсь получить некоторые значение из БД. Несколько раз запрос выполнился удачно, а затем они стал падать с ошибкой 500.
 Единственное, что меняла - объем запрашиваемых данных. На 1000 строк запрос сработал, на 2000 упал с ошибкой 500. После этого на всех запросах, вне зависимости от  объема запрашиваемых данных, получаю ошибку 500. Перезагрузка сервера не помогла.
 Пожалуйста, подскажите, как исправить эту ошибку?

Comment: https://www.jino.ru/help/faq/problems/error-500/

Comment: смотрите логи..

Comment: Данная ситуация возникла по моей вине(( я добавила в код новую функцию, и похоже, что IIS  на нее ругался